# Какие есть способы безопасного выполнение кода загруженного пользователем?

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность

Есть сервис который проверяет решение задач. Пользователь отправляет код, сервис прогоняет тестовые данные.
Как пример системы тренировки алгоритмов(leetcode, codewars).

Как изолировать выполнение кода пользователя, чтобы его код ничего не сломал?
Подскажите, какие есть варианты для решения данной проблемы, что почитать и изучить?

Comment: Изолирование процессов средствами операционной системы (песочницы sandbox) и возможно виртуализация процессов, чтобы скрыть еще основную систему + иметь несколько изолированных программных окружений. В общем уметь работать с линукс и возможностями виртуализации.

Comment: Подходит ли для этого Docker контейнеры?

Comment: Вышесказанное применимо и к ним, но все равно нужно настраивать систему внутри контейнера на безопасную работу и прокидывать данные в него для выполнения. К сожалению что-то конкретное по администрированию систем подсказать не могу.

Comment: Спасибо, буду дальше изучать :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать safe-eval, доступен в npm
https://github.com/hacksparrow/safe-eval

Comment: Прямо по вашей же ссылке в описании проекта написано, что он небезопасен. Ну а ещё в вопросе нигде не сказано, что речь только про js

Comment: Ниже версии подвержены уязвимости, на счет текущих информации нет

Comment: @Kenix там про текущую написано "There are still ways to crash the Node process"